# Uninitialized constant Van (NameError)

Tags: ruby, class

I am trying to write some functionality which allows me to take a broken bike to a garage to have it fixed, whilst implementing this i have come across this issue. i understand that this usually is because it cannot find the file but have ran out of ideas on how to fix it. If you need any of the other code let me know but i thought this would be all the code needed.

dockingstation.rb:

```
require_relative 'Bike'
require_relative 'van'
require_relative 'garage'

class DockingStation
  attr_reader :dock, :max_dock, :DEFAULT_CAPACITY

  DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 20
  def initialize(capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY)
    @max_dock = capacity
    @dock = []
  end

  def release_bike
    if !empty?
      @dock.each_with_index do |bike, index|
        if bike.working?
          @dock.delete_at(index)
          return bike
        else
          raise "Bike is broken"
        end
      end
    else
      raise "No bikes to release"
    end
  end

  def dock_bike(bike, working = true)
    if !full?
      @dock << bike
    else
      raise "Too many bikes"
    end
  end

  def show_dock
    @dock.each do |el|
      return el
    end
  end

  def van_takes_broken_bikes(van)
    puts @dock
    @dock.each_with_index do |bike, index|
        if bike.working? == true
            van.storage.append(bike)
        else
            van.storage.append(bike)
        end
    end
  end
  private def full?
    @dock.length == @max_dock
  end
  private def empty?
    @dock.length == 0
  end
end

dock = DockingStation.new
bike = Bike.new
van = Van.new
bike.report_broken
dock.dock_bike(bike)
dock.van_takes_broken_bikes(van)
```

van.rb:

```
require_relative 'dockingstation'
require_relative 'garage'

class Van
    attr_reader :storage
    def initialize
        @storage = []
    end
    def take_broken_bikes_to_garage(bikes)

    end
end
```

Comment: I have voted to close this question because the example given is unusable. You didn't include your `Bike` class. You've included way more methods and code than is necessary to reproduce the problem. You haven't explained how you're running your commands like `dock = DockingStation.new` -- are you using a REPL? How are you requiring the classes in your REPL? Or are those commands being run in some other file not shown here? Where's your stack trace? What line triggers the error? I suggest reading [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you post the error and a code snippet of the file we could understand better the issue. Anyway, it seems the problem is that the class `Van` is not defined. Try to past that class code in the file where the error occurs, if that solves the issue check the way you `require_relative` a file. For example, why is `Bike`, when you require it on line 1, capitalized? That should be a file name and by convention, you'de better use all small letters.